# See in which AppDomain an object is loaded

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, appdomain

When inspecting an object in the debugger, is it possible to see in which `AppDomain` the object is loaded? I mean: without coding any properties or methods in the object that return the current AppDomain. The various windows in the Visual Studio menu (Debug > Windows) do not seem to show this information at the object level.

Comment: You can use SOS.dll for this, there's a good article on it on MSDN [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/7f12f6ad-2a6e-4b14-897a-a9ee892d2ab5/)

Comment: AppDomain.CurrentDomain?

Comment: he said an object's appdomain, in the visual studio debugger

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio -> debug -> windows -> modules